# URI is not registered. jasypt in blueprint.xml

Tags: osgi, jbossfuse, fuse, jasypt, blueprint

I used jasypt for encryption in blueprint.xml of my OSGI application which'll be deployed in Jboss fuse server,

xmlns:enc="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/jasypt/v1.0.0

I'm seeing an error message in the xml file that "URI is not registered". I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE.

Can someone help me to resolve this? Should I need add any jar? Or any xsi:schemaLocation?

Comment: Have you installed the jasypt-encryption feature ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was actually trying out different jar, which doesn't have the xsd. This's now resolved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This's resolved, after adding the below dependency on my pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.karaf.jaas</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.karaf.jaas.jasypt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency jar has the xsd karat-jasypt-1.0.0.xsd in it.